# Flow: Missing type annotation for `OP`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, flowtype

I have a component connected to Redux store with Flow types.
I use:

```
"flow-bin": "^0.89.0",
"flow-typed": "^2.5.1",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
```

I set types for mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps functions

My index.js

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import type { Dispatch } from 'redux';
import type { DispatchProps, StateProps, NotificationItem, NotificationsProps, State, OwnProps } from './index.types';
import { createNotificationAction, createRemoveNotificationAction } from './redux';
import View from './View';

function Notifications(props: NotificationsProps) {
  return <View {...props} />;
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ notifications }: State): StateProps => ({ notifications });

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<*>): DispatchProps => ({
  removeNotification: (item: NotificationItem) => dispatch(createRemoveNotificationAction(item)),
  createNotification: (item: NotificationItem) => dispatch(createNotificationAction(item)),
});

const Connected = connect<NotificationsProps, OwnProps, StateProps, DispatchProps, State, Dispatch<*>>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Notifications);

export default Connected;
```

index.types.js

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';
import type { NotificationItem } from './redux';

export type StoreNotifications = {
  notifications: Array<NotificationItem>,
}

export type MapStateToProps = StoreNotifications

export type MapDispatchToProps = {
  removeNotification: (item: NotificationItem) => any,
  createNotification: (item: NotificationItem) => any,
}

export type NotificationsProps = {
  children: React.Node,
} & MapStateToProps & MapDispatchToProps;
```

Flow show me an errors of connect function:

```
Flow: Missing type annotation for `OP`. `OP` is a type parameter declared in function type [1] and was implicitly instantiated at call of `connect` [2].
```

When I've set return values of my `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` I have another issue:

```
Flow: inexact `MapDispatchToProps` [1] is incompatible with exact object type [2].
```

EDIT: 
I've updated my index.js:

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import type { Dispatch } from 'redux';
import type { DispatchProps, StateProps, NotificationItem, NotificationsProps, State, OwnProps } from './index.types';
import { createNotificationAction, createRemoveNotificationAction } from './redux';
import View from './View';

function Notifications(props: NotificationsProps) {
  return <View {...props} />;
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ notifications }: State): StateProps => ({ notifications });

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<*>): DispatchProps => ({
  removeNotification: (item: NotificationItem) => dispatch(createRemoveNotificationAction(item)),
  createNotification: (item: NotificationItem) => dispatch(createNotificationAction(item)),
});

const Connected = connect<NotificationsProps, OwnProps, StateProps, DispatchProps, State, Dispatch<*>>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Notifications);

export default Connected;
```

And types file:

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';

export type NotificationItem = {
  id: string,
  title: string,
  type: 'success' | 'warning' | 'danger',
  message: string,
  code: string,
  delay: number,
}

export type State = { +notifications: Array<NotificationItem> }

export type StateProps = {| +notifications: Array<NotificationItem> |}

export type DispatchProps = {|
  removeNotification: (item: NotificationItem) => any,
  createNotification: (item: NotificationItem) => any,
|}

export type OwnProps = {|
  children: React.Node
|}

export type NotificationsProps = { ...StateProps, ...DispatchProps, ...OwnProps };
```

And I have no flow issues, but I have lint issue in index JS in this line:

```
const Connected = connect<NotificationsProps, OwnProps, StateProps, DispatchProps, State, Dispatch<*>>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Notifications);
```

Right after `OwnProps`:

```
Eslint parsing error. Unexpected parsing error
```

My babel settings:

```
"babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
"eslint": "^5.4.0",
"eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
"eslint-config-standard-react": "^7.0.0",
"eslint-loader": "^2.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.50.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.12.0",
"eslint-plugin-jest": "^21.17.0",
"eslint-plugin-node": "^6.0.1",
"eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.7.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.8.2",
"eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
"flow-typed": "^2.5.1",
```

I'm digging into babel & eslint versions

Comment: Did you read docs for react-redux usage with flow 0.89? https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/react-redux_v5.x.x/flow_v0.89.x-/react-redux_v5.x.x.js#L2

Comment: Also, see tests for examples https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/react-redux_v5.x.x/flow_v0.89.x-/test_connectDispatch.js

Comment: @AlexSavin, thanks, I'll check out it

Comment: @AlexSavin I've updated my component code and types, and now I'm bumped into parsing error. I will appreciate if you'll check out my next message in topic. Thanx

Comment: @AlexSavin after I have updated my container, types as I put to a topic, all my issues has gone

Comment: Works on my machine (he-he) with babel-eslint 10.x and babel 7.x